SSL not working in NGINX ingress controller, TLS settings
I am trying to expose my application over TLS, Secure connection, below is my YAML config, I am unable to access my application over SSL for some reason help is required, I am using the nginx ingress controller, I have created secret using certificates

This is example "api.some.eu" domain I am also not able to use direct external host IP over
SSL but I am able to access both over HTTP only

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-access-log: "true"
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: api.some.eu  
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: geo-language-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/geolanguage(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: admin-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/admin(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: security-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/security(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: registry-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/registry(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: core-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/core(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: sms-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/sms(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: api-gateway-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.some.eu
    secretName: api-gateway-tls


do following  check
You have the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2 annotation. This is used to rewrite the request URL before forwarding it to the backend service. Ensure this is the desired behavior, as incorrect rewrite rules might cause unexpected issues.
and also ensure that the secret api-gateway-tls is correctly created and associated with the domain api.some.eu.
so check with command and  update more details about  error log
kubectl describe secret api-gateway-tls -n default

I can post logs from ingress if you want me to for some insight @divyang4481

yes, it can provide better info
